# Как установить пакет без apt update и apt upgrade

Tags: linux, apt

Использую ОС, которая поддерживает только подключение через Tor, потому команды `apt update` и `apt upgrade` занимают много времени. Как быстро установить пакет, не применяя эти команды?

Comment: [`dpkg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg.1.html)?

Comment: @wchistow зависимости....

Answer (score 1):

На той машинке [Закрытой] установить с трудом `apt-offline`

Например нам нужно postgresql-16 postgresql-client-16 и обновления

На закрытой выполнить

```
apt-offline set apt-offline.sig  --update --upgrade  --install-packages postgresql-16 postgresql-client-16
```

Перекинуть apt-offline.sig на открытую машинку с той же осью и выполнить на ней

```
mkdir debs
apt-offline get apt-offline.sig -d debs --bundle postgres.zip
```

Перекинуть zip на закрытую машинку и там установить то что скачивает apt update и кеш пакетов

```
apt-offline install postgres.zip
apt upgrade
apt install postgresql-16 postgresql-client-16
```

Apt подумает что все файлы уже скачены  и поставит из кеша

> Необходимо скачать 0 B/16,9 MB архивов.